# Three.js stretched texture

Tags: three.js

I am trying to get these textures to stretch equally but for some reason it is stretching it in the middle. Any advice?

I have set:

```
newTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
newTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```

and also

```
newTexture.repeat.set(1,1);
```

I have tried that repeat with multiple values and multiple textures but I still get the stretching on the sides:

[image]
[image]

the images are in a powerof2 format at 2048 and increasing the repeat values only tricks the eye a little to make it seem as if it isn't stretched but either way the pattern needs to be bigger rather than smaller with it repeating a lot more.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the uv (texture) coordinates on your mesh are what is introducing the stretching. You will need to remap the Uvs with an undistorted mapping in your modelling software and re-export it.